# How to find the voltage across a resistor in a RCL circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

In the circuit below I am trying to find an expression for the voltage across $R2$.
I have found an expression for the voltage across R1 which I have confirmed with a simulation, but I can't get it right for R2.
My solution for R1 is obtain by first handling the parallel impedance of R2, R_spole, L1 and C1, and then using the voltage divider rule.

$$V(R1) =Vin \cdot \frac{Z(R1)}{Z(R1)+\frac{(Z(R2)+Z(Rspole)+Z(L1))\cdot Z(C1)}{(Z(R2)+Z(Rspole)+Z(L1))+Z(C1)}}$$

Can anyone help with doing the same for R2?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you know $V(R1)$, you can subtract it from $V_{in}$ to get the voltage across the L1, Rspole, R2 combination. Then you can use the voltage divider equation again to get the voltage across R2.

An alternative way, if you were starting from scratch, would be to convert V_in, R1, and C1 into a Thevenin equivalent circuit, then again use the voltage divider rule on the simplified circuit to find the voltage across R2.